# localhost/phpmyadmin config problem, conflict with previous localhost FileMaker

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, localhost

6 months ago, I used FileMaker platform and set my localhost for Filemaker at that time! now I want to set my localhost for phpMyAdmin, "localhost/phpMyAdmin". I have done all the things right.
But, when write "localhost" still see the below page.

[image]

- I activated Apache and PHP.
- I have loaded : "sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf" and deleted # before "#LoadModule php7".
- I have MAC, thus I've created the "Sites" folder and added a file named index.php with the required codes in it.
- I also changed DirectoryRoot and

I have done all above mentioned steps by fallowing instruction in here "https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps"

I don't know what to do now ?!

Comment: have you checked what port filemaker is running from / Apache?

Comment: if your url is localhost/phpmyadmin then the folder structure behind is just that phpmyadmin is in a folder under your root dir. No need for virtual hosts. If you don't want to see the old content just remove what else is in the root directory that is coming from filemaker

Comment: Dear Jack: filemaker using port 80!

Comment: Dear Lelio Faieta: by root directory, you mean -> /Library/WebServer/Documents ?
or User/navid/Sites ?
i deleted everything there (3 files: 2 pictures and one index.http

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all FileMaker Server from my computer and the problem solved without any other change!
I still wonder what should I do if I want to have two localhosts!

1- localhost port 80 for Filemaker server
2- localhost port 90 for phpMyAdmin